# Draw line on run time WPF

Tags: wpf, line

I want to draw line on run time using mouse.I have tried in below way

```
 private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement f = e.Source as FrameworkElement;
        FrameworkElement pr = f.Parent as FrameworkElement;
        Rect feRect = f.TransformToAncestor(pr).TransformBounds(
                      new Rect(0.0, 0.0, f.ActualWidth, f.ActualHeight));
        Image image = sender as Image;


        Point textLocation = e.GetPosition(image);

        textLocation.Offset(-4, -4);
        var Top = feRect.Height - textLocation.Y;
        var Bottom = textLocation.Y - 1;
        var Left = textLocation.X - 1;
        var Right = feRect.Width-textLocation.X;


        // Create an annotation where the mouse cursor is located.and add control using adorner layer
        _currentAnnotations = ImageAnnotation.Create(
            image,
            textLocation,
            feRect
            );


    }
  private void Image_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            Image image = sender as Image;

            EndPosition = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(image);
            // Draw next line and...
            l.X1 = StartPosition.X;
            l.X2 = EndPosition.X;
            l.Y1 = StartPosition.Y;
            l.Y2 = EndPosition.Y;
            l.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
            l.StrokeThickness = 5;


            StartPosition = EndPosition;
        }
        if(_currentAnnotations!=null && l!=null)
        _currentAnnotations.Lines = l;

    }
```

But it doesn't give the result as expected. the line that am getting is different from the mouse location. my output should be like a pen tool.                1.what's wrong with my way?
2. Is inkCanvas the only way to draw line in wpf?if yes why so?
3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.what's wrong with my way?

You could try to set the `StartPosition` property in the `Image_MouseLeftButtonDown` event handler:

```
private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement f = e.Source as FrameworkElement;
    FrameworkElement pr = f.Parent as FrameworkElement;
    Rect feRect = f.TransformToAncestor(pr).TransformBounds(
                  new Rect(0.0, 0.0, f.ActualWidth, f.ActualHeight));
    Image image = sender as Image;
    ...
    StartPosition = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(image);
}
```

`InkCanvas` is the only built-in WPF control that receives and displays ink strokes. But you could for example add lines to a `Canvas` or perform any other kind of custom drawing action yourself.

Here is a basic sample that should give you the idea.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Point EndPosition;
    Point StartPosition;

    private void canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            FrameworkElement fe = sender as FrameworkElement;

            EndPosition = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(fe);

            Line l = new Line();
            l.X1 = StartPosition.X;
            l.X2 = EndPosition.X;
            l.Y1 = StartPosition.Y;
            l.Y2 = EndPosition.Y;
            l.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
            l.StrokeThickness = 5;

            StartPosition = EndPosition;
            canvas.Children.Add(l);
        }
    }

    private void canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
        StartPosition = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(fe);
    }
}
```

---

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas" Width="500" Height="500" Background="Yellow"
    MouseLeftButtonDown="canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="canvas_MouseMove" />
```

Comment: e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(image) and e.GetPosition(image) both are returning the same value

Comment: So? What do you mean?

Comment: @user3610920 that is correct they do, they are different ways to access the same method, the difference is that you are writting the getposition to a local variable that is wiped after the event complete were mm8 is using a class field

Comment: I can able to draw a line using canvas as you mentioned. Now in my sample am trying to use the canvas by means of adorner layer. with this concept the canvas control doesn't work as expected.Please find my sample from https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkJN2C0AKFNfeuR5CZ2BfZysjr8 . What's wrong with my sample

Comment: Please ask antother question if you have an additional issue. Don't ask additional questions in the comments section.